# Concatenar 2 repetidores de strings

Tags: javascript, string

`Necesito hacer un array que haga una escalera con numerales, antes del numeral tiene que haber un espacio, en el primer "escalón" hay la misma cantidad de espacios que escalones - 1, en el segundo - 2, y así, lo que necesito es concatenar los dos repetidores, dejo lo que tengo escrito hasta ahora.

```
function escalera(numero){
  var escalera = [];

  for(var i= 1; i <= numero; i++){

    for(var a =1; a < numero; a++){
      var escalon = " ".repeat(numero-a) + "#".repeat(i);

    }


    escalera.push(escalon);

  }
  return(escalera)

}
```

Así se debería ver:

`escalera(5) = [
  "    #",
  "   ##",
  "  ###",
  " ####",
  "#####"
]`

Comment: Creo que sería mejor que añadieras algún ejemplo de la salida que esperas para que se pueda entender mejor.

Comment: ¿Y no es eso lo que obtienes con tu función?

Comment: No, por solo agrega un espacio a cada string. Así: [ ' #', ' ##', ' ###' ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad no necesitas dos bucles. Puedes hacer uno sólo y añades tantos elementos `#` como `i` y tantos espacios como la diferencia del total menos `i`:

```js
function escalera(numero){
  var escalera = [];
  for(var i= 1; i <= numero; i++){
    var escalon = " ".repeat(numero-i) + "#".repeat(i);
    escalera.push(escalon);
  }
  return(escalera)
}

console.log(escalera(5));
```

Comment: muchas gracias.